# How can I duplicate an array based on an internal array using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I've managed to chop down the initial file into a final array that I want, but I'm uncertain on how to manipulate it. I have a clear before and desired "after";

**Before:**

```
[
  "Access Token Manipulation",
  "T1134",
  [
    {
      "kill_chain_name": "mitre-attack",
      "phase_name": "defense-evasion"
    },
    {
      "kill_chain_name": "mitre-attack",
      "phase_name": "privilege-escalation"
    }
  ]
]
```

**After:**

```
[
  "Access Token Manipulation",
  "T1134",
  "defense-evasion"
]
[
  "Access Token Manipulation",
  "T1134",
  "privilege-escalation"
]
```

I'll convert this with @csv afterwards, but the objects need to be split up first. Part of me thinks that recurse or a foreach works, but another part of me thinks that this is just so simple and I'm looking over something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the first two elements in a variable, extract the phase name and add it to the variable:

```
jq '[.[0],.[1]] as $h | .[2][].phase_name | $h + [.]'
```